# my ag shortcut chokes on spaces

Tags: command-line, external-command, the-silver-searcher, vimgrep

I got this in my .vimrc:

```
set grepprg=grep\ -nriI\ --exclude=tags\ --exclude-dir=vendor

" The Silver Searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use ag over grep
  let &grepprg = "ag --nogroup --nocolor --ignore wiki --ignore tags --ignore tests --ignore dist -w"

  ..
endif

" bind \ (backward slash) to grep shortcut
command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
```

when I type <kbd>\</kbd> the prompt turns into `:Ag`, when I search for single words, it works like a charm. But when I search for sentences with spaces in between (even if i enclose with `"`) nothing works.. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why It's Broken

The problem is that you've used `-bar` in your command definition. This attribute is used to specify that you can use a `|` after an *invocation* of your new command e.g.:

```
:Ag search_term | copen
```

However, the `-bar` flag also checks for `"` characters to start a comment (See :help :command-bar.)

This means that when you issue the command:

```
:Ag "find me"
```

The `"find me"` is interpreted as a comment, resulting in Vim running the command:

```
:Ag
```

...and you get the following error (because you specified that arguments are required with `-nargs=+`):

```
E471: Argument required
```

### Workarounds

One workaround is to use `'` characters instead (noting [the difference between the two when used in e.g. bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) — now you can no longer search for things containing single quotes):

```
:Ag 'find me'
```

Alternatively, you can escape whitespace:

```
:Ag find\ me
```

### How to Fix It

However, you can also simply remove the `-bar` attribute:

```
command -nargs=+ -complete=file Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
```

*N.B. It is not necessary to use the `-bar` attribute to allow the use of `|` in the* definition *of a command, in case that's why you added it.*

After doing so, all of the following will work:

```
:Ag find\ me
:Ag 'find me'
:Ag "Can't find me"
```

### Extra Credit

If you don't *want* to have to use quotes or escaping when invoking `:grep` or `:Ag`, you can get Vim to do the escaping for you:

```
function! Ag(args) abort
  execute "silent! grep!" shellescape(a:args)
  cwindow
  redraw!
endfunction

command -nargs=+ -complete=file Ag call Ag(<q-args>)
```

Now this works:

```
:Ag find me
```

Comment: wow.. vim is an ocean, and you guys are the experienced navigators.. you got my appreciation, and respect.

Comment: hey Rich my ag stil l doesn't find something like this `Mail::queueOn`.. it seems the `::` are messing things up?

Comment: @abbood I just copied the code above into a new `.vimrc` and it seems to find `Mail::queueOn` fine (I tested both versions). What output do you get if you replace `execute` with `echom` command, run `Ag::queueOn`, and then run the command `:messages`?