# How to keep Ag (the silver searcher) open when no matches are found?

Tags: vimrc, the-silver-searcher

I do use Ag as my grep replacement. My problem is that when I search for something that does not exist (search result empty) my quick fix windows closes automatically.

Is that normal? Would it be possible to keep it open with something like "No results found" ?

This is my config

```
" bind \ (backward slash) to grep shortcut
" https://robots.thoughtbot.com/faster-grepping-in-vim
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14923/my-ag-shortcut-chokes-on-spaces
function! Ag(args) abort
  execute "silent! grep!" shellescape(a:args)
  cwindow
  redraw!
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ -complete=file Ag call Ag(<q-args>)
nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using [`:cwindow`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#:cwindow) to open the window.

See `:help :cwindow`:

> Open the quickfix window when there are recognized
>               errors.  If the window is already open and there are
>               no recognized errors, **close the window.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Change this to `:copen` to always open the quickfix window.

If you want the window to display "No results found" instead of just being empty, you will also need an autocommand:

```
augroup AgQuickfix
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPost quickfix setlocal modifiable
        \ | if line('$') == 1 && empty(getline(1))
        \ |   call setline(1, "No results found") 
        \ | endif
        \ | setlocal nomodifiable
augroup END
```

This is described in `:help quickfix.txt` (search for `BufReadPost`).