# Ever since I moved from Vim to Neovim, my ag has started acting strange

Tags: neovim, the-silver-searcher

I recently switched to Neovim, but ever since my `ag` usage have acted weird lately. Here is my current [.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/abbood/80b5396ab461cc731f1ed4261808f7c0) file.

Here is my Neovim init file `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath=&runtimepath
source ~/.vimrc
let g:python3_host_prog='/Users/abdullah/.pyenv/shims/python3'
let g:python_host_prog='/Users/abdullah/.pyenv/shims/python'
```

Here are the problems I'm facing:

**When I search the current keyword, I get a preview of the results, before actually *seeing* the results**

So suppose I place the cursor ontop of `attachClusteredOrders` here

```
public static function attachClusteredOrders($orders, float $distanceThreshold, int $backtrackDays)
```

**actual behavior**

I get this preview of search results with the prompt to enter a command to continue:
[image]

Once I enter <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I see this

[image]

**expected behaviour**

I should see the search results directly without having to enter <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note: here is the relevant part from my vimrc on this:

```
" The Silver Searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use ag over grep
  let &grepprg = "ag --nogroup --nocolor --ignore wiki --ignore tags --ignore dist --ignore tests --ignore seeds --ignore migrations -w"

  " Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'

  " ag is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
  let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
endif

" bind K to grep word under cursor
nnoremap K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>

" command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
" above replaced with
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14939/14510
function! Ag(args) abort
  execute "silent! grep!" shellescape(a:args)
  cwindow
  redraw!
endfunction
```

---

**When I run my keyboard shortcut to launch AG, nothing happens**

**actual behaviour**

I run my keyboard shortcut to start the AG prompt <kbd>\</kbd> and then I see this

[image]

but when I type enter nothing happens. But if I manually type `:Ag <query>` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> it works just fine!

**expected behaviour**

The keyboard shortcut should work from the first time

Note: relevant part of my vimrc:

```
" bind \ (backward slash) to grep shortcut
nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
```

Answer (score 0):

this fix worked for me so far but I'm not too happy about it b/c it still shows the intermediary output for a second then it shows the results, I'd rather it jumped straight to the results instead.

```
" bind K to grep word under cursor
nnoremap K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR><ENTER>
```